# How to colour vector tiles based on filter in QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style, filter, vector-tiles

I have a vector tiles layer that displays fine in QGIS 3.16:

[image: Vector tiles with properties in identify results / QGIS 3.16]

A fill without a filter works as well:

[image: Hashed fill for vector tiles in QGIS 3.16]

However, the fill based on a filter on the feature properties does not work (result can be seen in image 1). Note that "Lines" and "Points" are added automatically by QGIS.

[image: Styling vector tiles based on filter in QGIS 3.16 not working]

How can I set the symbology based on an attribute of the vector tiles?

Comment: I don't get why there's a line and a point style.

Comment: They are configured automatically by QGIS. When you open the Symbology tab for the first time, there are three entries: Polygons, Lines, Points.

Comment: "Lines" are actually the outlines of the Polygons in the first image. That is weird, since I can define the outline via the Polygon style as well.

Comment: I think rule based symbology can overcome this problem. After selecting rule based symbology, you can set filters.

Comment: Where can I select rule based symbology? It seems that this option does not exist for vector tiles layers (or at least I cannot find it).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the "Layer" attribute in the "Layer Properties" window that you're showing above. Right now, it shows "(all layers)"; try changing it (by highlighting the corresponding cells and pressing F2 to the appropriate layer name. I think it might be "default", judging from your screenshots.